# Error SoftLayer_Exception_Public. (SoftLayer_Dns_Domain_Registration:: modifyContact)

Tags: rest, exception, ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-infrastructure, ims

I am having trouble with the **modifyContact** call. Every time I try to execute it I receive the error:

```
{
"error": "Internal Error",
"code": "SoftLayer_Exception_Public"
}
```

**URL**

https://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Dns_Domain_Registration/modifyContact/

**CURL Request**

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Dns_Domain_Registration/modifyContact.json' \
--header 'InitParameters: 610994' \
--header 'Authorization: Basic <Token>' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "contact": {
        "id": "610994",
        "address1": "11501 Burnet Rd",
        "address2": "TX",
        "city": "Austin",
        "country": "US",
        "email": "softlayer-test@test.amsdfw.us",
        "firstName": "Jeroen",
        "lastName": "Schaftenaar",
        "organizationName": "SoftLayer Internal - IBM Interface Development",
        "phone": "+1.2142142145",
        "postalCode": "78758-3420",
        "state": "TX",
        "type": "owner"
    }
}
```

Comment: Try using this curl command: curl -u $username:$apikey -X POST -H "Accept: */*" -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, compress" -d '{"parameters": [{"address1": "11501 Burnet Rd", "address2": "TX", "city": "Austin", "country": "US", "email": "softlayer-test@test.amsdfw.us", "firstName": "Jeroen", "lastName": "Schaftenaar", "organizationName": "SoftLayer Internal - IBM Interface Development", "phone": "+1.2142142145", "postalCode": "78758-3420", "state": "TX", "type": "owner"}]}' 'https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Dns_Domain_Registration/610994/modifyContact.json'